# Является ли конструктор объектов дизайн-паттерном?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, терминология

Является ли конструктор объектов дизайн-паттерном?

Comment: что здесь имеется ввиду под конструктором объектов? Что считать _дизайн-паттерном_?

Comment: создание объектов через new.

Comment: "A pattern is a reusable solution that can be applied to commonly occurring problems in software design"

Comment: нет, не является.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Паттерн если проще и по русски это приём программирования.

Конструктор это базовая возможность языка, с этой стороны я бы не сказал что он является паттерном. При этом конструкторы есть в большинстве ООП языков.
Оператор = например если тоже рассмотреть, это же не паттерн, это базовый оператор.

Я бы сказал так, что это базовые операции, которые лежат ещё до паттернов.

Но если рассмотреть с более общей позиции языков программирования, то можно и паттерном назвать, но на мой взгляд это было бы притянуто за уши, по крайней мере в контексте Java или C#, согласно здравому смыслу и общей терминологии.